# Add search functionality to call log in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made an Android app that displays the call log based on the call type ( incoming calls, outgoing calls, missing calls, etc) but I want to implement a search functionality to the app as well as add deletion functionality of each call log.  Any idea on how this could be done?  I can add the layout file as well as needed. Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    TextView show;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        show=findViewById(R.id.calls_text);
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG))
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},1);

            }
            else
            {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG},1);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            getCallDetails();
            String calls = getCallDetails();
            show.setText(calls);
        }

    }

    String getCallDetails()
    {
        StringBuilder sbin=new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbout=new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder missed=new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sbin.append("Incoming Calls :\n");
        sbout.append("Outgoing Calls :\n");
        missed.append("Missed Calls :\n");
        Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
        assert managedCursor != null;
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        while(managedCursor.moveToNext())
        {
            String pnumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String ctype = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String cdate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date cdaydate = new Date(Long.parseLong(cdate));
            SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
            String cdatetime = formater.format(cdaydate);
            String cduration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String dir="";
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(ctype);
            switch (dircode)
            {
                case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                    dir+="OUTGOING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                    dir+="INCOMING";
                    break;
                case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                    dir+="MISSED";
                    break;
            }

            if(dir.equalsIgnoreCase("OUTGOING"))
                sbout.append("\nPhoneNumber: ").append(pnumber).append("\ntype: ").append(dir).append("\ndate : ").append(cdatetime).append("\nduration : ").append(cduration).append("\n\n");

            if(dir.equalsIgnoreCase("INCOMING"))
                sbin.append("\nPhoneNumber: "+pnumber+"\ntype: "+dir+"\ndate : "+cdatetime+"\nduration : "+cduration+"\n\n");

            if(dir.equalsIgnoreCase("MISSED"))
                missed.append("\nPhoneNumber: "+pnumber+"\ntype: "+dir+"\ndate : "+cdatetime+"\nduration : "+cduration+"\n\n");

        }
        managedCursor.close();
        sbout.append("-------------------------\n");
        sbin.append("-------------------------\n");
        missed.append("-------------------------\n");
        sb.append(sbin);
        sb.append(sbout);
        sb.append(missed);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the search try adding the logs to a list then using listView and searchview

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);  
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);  

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {  
        @Override  
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {  

            if(list.contains(query)){  
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);  
            }else{  
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Match found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
            }  
            return false;  
        }  
        @Override  
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {  
            return false;  
        }  
    });  
}
```

For delete functionality

```
void deleteLog(String number){
    String queryString = "NUMBER=" + number; 
    getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, queryString, null);  
}
```